# datatables loop through all table rows, only did loop on the currently shown table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

im trying to loop to all table rows on the datatables table but only did loop unto currently shown table rows like i have 100 records (100 table rows) and currently shown 10 table rows, it did only loop unto 10 table rows unfortunately.

I used below codes on looping through each table rows

```
$("#admin_user_table tbody tr").each(function(){
    alert("yes");
});
```

any ideas, help, clues, suggestions, recommendations?

below is my fiddle to be more specific.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#sample_table').DataTable( {
        "bSort": false,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    });
  
  $("#test_loop").click(function(){
    $("#sample_table tbody tr").each(function(){
      alert("table row");
   });
  });
  
});
```

```css
table{width: 100%}table td, table th{padding: 7px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle}table thead{border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc;}table tbody tr{border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>



<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="sample_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Branch</th>
      <th>Department</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td><td>Sample position</td><td>sample branch</td><td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button id="test_loop">Loop through all the table rows</button>
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way if the table is populated dynamically using ajax...

Comment: the table is not populated by ajax @ArunPJohny

Comment: then how is the paging done...

Comment: also why do you want to iterate through all the items... if the data is preloaded why can't you just iterate over the data

Comment: I use datatables plugin "https://www.datatables.net/" the plugin will take care of everything e.g. "paging, sorting, search, filtering" all I have to do is to put all the necessary table tags and content.

Comment: I just need to hide some table rows for my requirements thats why im trying to loop through all the table rows to check that rows needed to be hide.

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/

Comment: see how it should be done - https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: @Arun P Johny: please see my updated post, i included my fiddle to be more specific. Please click unto the button to loop on each tr, you can see that it loops only unto the current shown table rows.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8ybnoyx7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [raw filter](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/#Row-based-search)

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var enabled = $('#my-filter').is(':checked');        
        return !enabled || /raw$/g.test(data[1]);
    }
);

$(document).ready(function() {

 var table =  $('#sample_table').DataTable({
    "bSort": false,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
  });

  $("#my-filter").change(function() {
    table.draw();
  });

});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%
}
table td,
table th {
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle
}
table thead {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc;
}
table tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>



<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="sample_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Branch</th>
      <th>Department</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample raw</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Name 1</td>
      <td>Sample position</td>
      <td>sample branch</td>
      <td>sample department</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input id="my-filter" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: it seems a little bit complicated but good. in my experiment conclusion, It seems that the loop function can completely loop through all the table rows if I show all the rows first. So im taking other approach where I should show first all the table row before ill loop on each table rows, is there a way I could show all the rows when click the button? surely I can use "paging : false" but I dont know how to do it, and then also turn the paging to true when click another button (let say, the button named is "restore table rows") is that possible?